# Laptop touchpad and keyboard not working in wayland / gdm3

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, laptop, 21.10, wayland

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 21.10 from 20.10 (it was a bit painful because of End Of Life) on my ASUS laptop.
After the upgrade, I realised that I could no longer use my keyboard and touchpad in the login screen of GDM3. I needed to plug in an external mous and keyboard to be able to log in. Everything was back to normal once logged in.

I figured out that my normal session is in fact an X session, while GDM3 is running on wayland.
I uncommented (removed the `#`) `EnableWayland=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. It solved my issue.
Still, I should not have to do this and the touchpad and keyboard should work in wayland, especially that ubuntu is progressively migrating towards wayland.

I also noted that GDM does not give me a choice of sessions any longer, so I had to find out how to know which kind of session I was running via command line to be able to pin down the difference between working touchpad in session and not working touchpad during login.

Edit: to update from 20.10 to 21.10 I was first stuck because of packaging errors (which stemmed, as I found out much later, from sophos-av which denys access to specific dpkg files when not disabled). I first tried to do a 20.10 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 upgrade, but the first did not work because of said errors. I then tried to downgrade to the more ancient LTS release (20.04) by manually editing all the apt-sources files, which obviously did not work. Finally I used a bootable USB to chroot into my system and do the 20.10 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 upgrades, after fixing the errors in my dependencies in 20.10 with multiple apt upgade, apt --fix-missing, etc. iterations, depending on what apt told me to do. These upgrades succeeded. I also got rid of sophos, as they do not provide free updates to the virus database any longer.

To cut a long story short: X recognises my keyboard and touchpad, wayland doesn't. I might have had wayland disabled already in the previous install, but while upgrading I usually prefer the distributor's configuration files rather than mine, especially for more fundamental changes in the system

Comment: How did you upgrade from 20.10 to 21.10? As there is no direct path at this time, the process that was followed may have resulted in the gaps. Could you [edit] your question to outline the steps you followed?

Comment: @matigo: ok I did